# How do I hide projects?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I have a large VS solution, but I'm only working on two different projects, but need all the projects loaded to do the build.

Is it possible to just see the projects I am interested in without changing the structure of the solution for build purposes?

If it's not possible, but work-arounds are available?

Comment: Can't you create your own (local) solution containing only those 2 projects and all the relevant dll as references ? This way you don't have to change anything in the original solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can right click a project --> "New solution explorer view" and then you can play with the windowconfiguration like this:
[image]

Comment: Although that only allows one project per new Solution Window, it's the closest I've seen.  I was also unaware of the feature even after using VS for years.

Comment: I created two of them for the two projects I'm working on, and docked them in different places.

Comment: Wish they would alow you to use the 'Scope to this' for multiple projects. That would have been perfect for you.

Answer (score 5):

I do it like this:

```
Right click solution | Add New Solution Folder
```

Then I just create some dummy folder. I drag all the projects and anything else I do not want to see into that folder.

```
Then right click the folder | Hide Folder
```

*Note*: If you work in a team environment, do not check in the solution file.

It works for me so hopefully it will work for you as well.

<sub>*If only I could create a folder and throw some of the people I can think of into it and do the above trick...*</sub>

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the "filtered solutions" feature of Visual Studio where you can unload specific projects then save off that as a visual studio solution filter file.

[Load a subset of projects - Visual Studio (Windows) | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/filtered-solutions?view=vs-2019#solution-filter-files)

It worked pretty good for my team and I.

Comment: From Review: Hi, while links are a great way of sharing knowledge, they won't really answer the question if they get broken in the future. Add to your answer the essential content of the link which answers the question. In case the content is too complex or too big to fit here, describe the general idea of the proposed solution. Remember to always keep a link reference to the original solution's website. See: [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)